# Bootstrap 4 beta grid 6 columns > 2 columns on resize

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

I need to make a grid with 6 columns in full screen that size down to 2 columns on smaller/mobile. Here is what I have tried so far. It looks correct wide, on my laptop, but when smaller, iPhone or tablet, it shows 6 columns still with very tiny images.

```html
<div class="row mb-3">
<div class="col filter bunarske">
               <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="references/logos/hardrock4.gif" /> </div>
                
<div class="col filter bunarske">
                     <img class="img-fluid" alt="Paragon Casino Resort" src="references/logos/paragon.jpg"> </div>
                 
<div class="col filter bunarske">
                <img class="img-fluid" alt="Tuscon Center" src="references/logos/USHomeLogo.jpg">  </div>
                
<div class="col filter bunarske">
               <img class="img-fluid" alt="Choctaw Casino" src="references/logos/choctaw.jpg">  </div>
                
<div class="col filter bunarske">
                  <img class="img-fluid" alt="Trump 29 Casino" src="references/logos/trump29.jpg">  </div>
                 
<div class="col filter bunarske">
                 <img class="img-fluid" alt="Kimberly Clark" src="references/logos/KimberlyClarkLogo.jpg"> </div>
            </div>                 
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

http://pscompetitiveedge.com/references-test.html

Answer (score 0):

change `col-xs-2` to `col-xs-6`.

You have to sum up to 12 , each "sum" of colums to 12 is put into one row - thats how it works.

Comment: I edited my code. to  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```html
<div class="row flex-mb1">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>

<div class="col-xs-6  col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>

<div class="col-xs-6  col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
                                                                                                    
  <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>                                                                                                  
                                                                                                    <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-2"><a class="thumbnail fancybox" data-fancybox="images" href="original_photos/1.jpg">
                       <div class="img-fixed">
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="http://ryehome.com/original_photos/1.jpg" /> </div>
                     </a></div>
</div>
<!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
  <div class="clearfix d-none d-sm-block"></div>
```

you can change col-xs-12 to col-xs-6 if want to keep 2 cols even in extra small screen

Comment: that changes the 6 columns to 2 columns at approx 742px wide and and 550px wide makes it 1 column

Comment: You can make col -xs-6 that will do

Comment: that changes 6 columns in wide screen down to 1 at about 550px https://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/yzjRya

Comment: It is a issue with code pen....
It is working fine when run normally using a browser

Comment: I edited my code in the question and made a test page link, it still doesnt resize